# Populate Table after Combo Box Selection

Tags: sapui5

I have a table that is populated by OData but I want it to not populate when first loading the page.

How can I have it be empty until the user selects a choice in the combo box first? Is there suppose to be a change in the view, controller, or manifest?

#### View

```
<ComboBox id="officeComboBox"
    width="100%"
    placeholder="Office"
    selectionChange=".officeComboChange"
>
    <items>
        <core:Item key="{OFFICE_CODE}" text="{OFFICE_CODE}" textDirection="RTL"/>
    </items>
</ComboBox>
<!-- ... -->
<Table id="statTable"
    noDataText="Initializing Data"
    growing="true"
    includeItemInSelection="true"
    headerText="EST"
    items="{/ESTSet}"
>
```

#### Controller

Handler `officeCodeChange` works fine for displaying the right items on the table after combo box selection

```
onInit: function() {
    var oViewModel, iOriginalBusyDelay, oTable = this.byId("officeCombo");
    this._oTableSearchState = [];
},

officeCodeChange: function(event) {
    var aFilters = [];
    var officeCode = event.getParameter("selectedItem").getText();
    var filter = new Filter("EST_ID", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, officeCode);
    var list = this.getView().byId("statTable");
    var binding = list.getBinding("items");
    binding.filter(aFilters.concat(filter), "Application");
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the initial aggregation binding `items="{/ESTSet}"` and the corresponding template control from the view.
2. Use [`bindItems`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/methods/bindItems) in combination with the created filter(s):

   ```js
   officeCodeChange: function(event) {
     const filter = /*...*/;
     const table = this.byId("statTable");
     const listBinding = table.getBinding("items");
     if (listBinding) {
       listBinding.filter(filter, FilterType.Application); // FilterType required from "sap/ui/model/FilterType"
     } else {
       this.bindStats(table, filter);
     }
   },

   bindStats: function(table, filter) {
     table.bindItems({
       path: "/ESTSet",
       filters: [filter],
       template: new ColumnListItem({ // required from "sap/m/ColumnListItem"
         //...
       }),
     });
   },
   ```